# Vi editor text alignment

Tags: vim, vi

I am trying to copy a table from a excel file to VI editor text file. Currently the  format is as below:

```
abcsddsds 1.2
aabb 2.3
wwwww 4.5.1
ab 2
c 1
```

How I want it to be:

```
abcsddsds 1.2
aabb      2.3
wwwww     4.5.1
ab        2
c         1
```

In my search, my commands came up, such as :%!column -t which I don't understand. Please help.

Comment: Did you try `:%!column -t`? Seems to work fine for me. If you want to know what it's doing, a good place to start is vim's built-in help tool. Type `:help <command>` in normal mode to learn more about a command. In your case, try `:help :`, `:help :%`, and `:help !`.

Comment: using the ::%!column -t pops up another "column" window with expalanationSW and column tabs. At the bottom, if I click quit, my text file shows all items are filtered and becomes blank

Answer (score 5):

You can execute unix commands from within Vim using the `!<command>` syntax.

[column](https://man.cx/column) is a unix command which aligns the data neatly into columns. You supply it an argument of `-t` for it to autodetect the columns in the file (splitting by space).

So to break it up, you press the below keys in sequence within Vim to achieve what you need:

`Esc` to enter (or ensure you're already in) command mode
`:` and `%` to select whole file's contents
`!` to run the unix command which immediately follows
`column -t` the unix command which actually does the column formatting.

Alternatively, you can save the file in Vim without proper alignment, then run the command `column -t <source_file> > <aligned_file>` from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Using [vim tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) plugin (godlygeek/tabular) you can do something like:

```
:Tabularize /\d.*
```